# How mysql redo log files used in a circular fashion and whats the advantage?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

In Innodb we have two redo log files ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 by default.

in docs and all the blogs it is written that logs files are written in circular fashion, so what does it mean ?

It writes 1st transaction in first file and 2nd in second file and 3rd in first file and so on.
OR
all transaction in first file and then start the second file ?

If all transaction in first file and then start the second file then whats the advantage of 2 or more files rather than increasing the size of one file ?

Comment: i got that all transactions write in first file and then writes in second file so whats adv of 2 or more files